# Please help me to win the battle with 2 column loop by category

Tags: loop, columns

I need help with this code.
How can I change the code so that the posts from one category to be arranged like the this scheme. [scheme picture](http://www.picvalley.net/v.php?p=u/2455/193250090019420937401325705906biUpRgmJ0uJopq9iAnr5.PNG)

```
    <?php query_posts('cat=3&amp;showposts=1'); ?>
    <?php while(have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php
    $postcount++;
    if( ($postcount % 2) == 0 ) : // skip 'even' posts
        $wp_query->next_post();
    else :
    ?>
    <?php the_post(); ?>

                        <?php if ( function_exists( 'get_the_image' ) ) { get_the_image( array( 'custom_key' => array( 'post_thumbnail' ), 'default_size' => 'full','image_class' => 'alignleft', 'width' => '120', 'height' => '120' ) ); } ?>


    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>

    <?php $postcount = 0; rewind_posts(); ?>

    <div class="even-column">
    <?php query_posts('cat=3&amp;showposts=2'); ?>
    <?php while(have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php
    $postcount++;
    if( ($postcount % 2) != 0 ) : // skip 'odd' posts
        $wp_query->next_post();
    else :
    ?>
    <?php the_post(); ?>

                        <?php if ( function_exists( 'get_the_image' ) ) { get_the_image( array( 'custom_key' => array( 'post_thumbnail' ), 'default_size' => 'full', 'image_class' => 'alignleft', 'width' => '60', 'height' => '60' ) ); } ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use query_posts more than one time. It will create errors. You have to use `wp_query`.

Here is what it says in wordpress codex:

> **query_posts( is meant for altering the main loop**. Once you use
>   query_posts(), your post-related global variables and template tags
>   will be altered. Conditional tags that are called after you call
>   query_posts() will also be altered - this may or may not be the
>   intended result.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

```
<?php $query_one = new WP_Query('cat=3&amp;showposts=1'); ?>
<?php while($query_one->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php
$postcount++;
if( ($postcount % 2) == 0 ) : // skip 'even' posts
    $wp_query->next_post();
else :
?>
<?php $query_one->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php if ( function_exists( 'get_the_image' ) ) { get_the_image( array( 'custom_key' => array( 'post_thumbnail' ), 'default_size' => 'full','image_class' => 'alignleft', 'width' => '120', 'height' => '120' ) ); } ?>


<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();  // Important to reset it when done ?> 
</div>

<?php $postcount = 0; rewind_posts(); ?>

<div class="even-column">
<?php $query_two = new WP_Query('cat=3&amp;showposts=2'); ?>
<?php while($query_two->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php
$postcount++;
if( ($postcount % 2) != 0 ) : // skip 'odd' posts
    $wp_query->next_post();
else :
?>
<?php $query_two->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php if ( function_exists( 'get_the_image' ) ) { get_the_image( array( 'custom_key' => array( 'post_thumbnail' ), 'default_size' => 'full', 'image_class' => 'alignleft', 'width' => '60', 'height' => '60' ) ); } ?>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); // After every wp_query ?> 
</div>
```

You can read more about it here: 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Thnak you for the answer jocken. I read the article and it helped me a lot. Can I ask you a last question about my code?

Comment: Of course you can!

Answer (score 0):

[Don't repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) ;)

I think this should do it:

```
<?php
    query_posts( 'cat=3' );
    $postcount = 0;
    while( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();
        $image = false;

        if ( function_exists( 'get_the_image' ) ) :
            $image = get_the_image( array(
                'custom_key' => array(
                'post_thumbnail' ),
                'default_size' => 'full',
                'image_class' => 'alignleft',
                'width' => '120',
                'height' => '120',
                'echo' => false
            ) );
        endif;

        if( ($postcount % 2) == 0 )
            $images['even'][] = $image;
        else
            $images['odd'][] = $image;

        $postcount++;
    endwhile;

foreach ($images as $colname => $colimages )
{
    echo '<div class="' . $colname . '-column">';
    foreach ( $colimages as $img )
    {
        if ( $img != false )
            echo $img;
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Peter!
But i have two different sizes on the thumbnails.